# How to modify the value of v-model property via custom directive?

Tags: events, vue.js, vuejs2, directive, dom-events

When I use custom directive to change component's value, there is not effect:

```js
Vue.directive('maxchars', {
  bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    let maxChars = binding.value;
    let handler = function(e) {
      if (e.target.value.length > maxChars) {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.substr(0, maxChars)
      }
    }
    el.addEventListener('input', handler);
  }
});
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      content: '',
      totalCount: 140
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div>
    <div class='content'>
      <textarea v-model='content' v-maxchars='140'>tell me something</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when I use `v-bind:input` directive to change value is ok!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First:

- You are using `v-model`, the value of the `textarea` will be whatever is in the `v-model`'s variable (in this case, the variable `content`). This means that the **initial value of the DOM is ignored**.
- To handle this, I moved (see below) the string from the DOM declaration to the `content` in `data()`.

Second:

- Vue does not respond to changes in `.value` directly. `v-model` actually watches for `input`✱ events from the DOM element.

  - <sup><sub>✱ it actually varies depending on the type of element, sometimes it is the `change` event, or other</sub></sup>
- If you just set the `value`, Vue will simple override it back (to whatever is in `content`) next time an update happens.

### Solution:

**After changing the `.value`, trigger `input` event.** Vue will pick the event up and update the `v-model` variable from the current `.value` **before it overrides it**.

Demo:

```js
Vue.directive('maxchars', {
  bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    let maxChars = binding.value;
    let handler = function(e) {
      if (e.target.value.length > maxChars) {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.substr(0, maxChars);
        vnode.elm.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('input')); // added this
      }
    }
    el.addEventListener('input', handler);
  }
});
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      content: 'tell me something',
      totalCount: 140
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div>
    <div class='content'>
      <textarea v-model='content' v-maxchars='18'></textarea>
    </div>
    <pre>
    content: {{ content }}
    Max chars is 18, current is {{ content.length }}.
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be careful tho, CustomEvent is not supported in Internet Explorer.

Comment: why you need this while we already have `maxlength` attr in html ?

Comment: @santosh I agree, but I think the point is not so much about what we are doing with the model, but how to do it, that is, how to change the v-model prop via a custom directive. (As a side note, I recently had to implement a max-chars thing like this and preferred a twitter-like solution, showing how many chars were past allowed, instead of truncating them.)

Comment: You don't need to remove the event listener in `unbind`?

Comment: @abhim perhaps. Depending on your case, if the `el` will still be around, it probably is wise to remove the listener when `unbind`ing.

Comment: I realised the element won't be around, so why worry about unbinding it (facepalm)

Answer (score 6):

Just create a **input** event using **Event** function.

> var event = new Event("input", { bubbles: true });

then modify the value and then dispatch the event, it will update the v-model value

> el.dispatchEvent(event);

```
Vue.directive('maxchars', {
  update(el, binding, vnode) {
    var event = new Event("input", { bubbles: true });
    let maxChars = binding.value;
      if (el.value.length > maxChars) {
        el.value = e.value.substr(0, maxChars);
        el.dispatchEvent(event);
      }
  }
});
```

hope it will helpful.