# Vue directive to update input on blur

Tags: vue.js, dom-events, onblur, vue-directives

I'm trying to implement a directive that will trim the value of an input on blur event:

```js
import { DirectiveOptions } from "vue";

const Autotrim: DirectiveOptions = {
    inserted(el) {
        if(!(el instanceof HTMLInputElement) && !(el instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement)) {
            throw 'Cannot apply v-autotrim directive to a non-input element!';
        }

        el.addEventListener('blur', () => {
           if(el.value)
               el.value = el.value.trim();
        });
    }
};
```

The input is updated, but the bound value in the model is not, and after any change somewhere else in the component it reverts back to an un-trimmed state.

What is the correct way to ensure the model is also updated?

**EDIT** Here's a codepen link to try:
https://codepen.io/impworks/pen/mddMPyx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *trigger* the `input` *event* to let Vue know that value was changed.

Do this once you've detected that input value is different than current value (to avoid infinit recursion)

```js
if (el.value && el.value !== el.value.trim()) {
    el.value = el.value.trim();
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work for me. Please check the codepen link in the updated post: enter "   foo" as first name, press tab (see the trim in action), then start typing anything into last name and the trim will be undone

Comment: I've used the wrong event type, VueJS is listening to `input` event. I've tried the codepen example with `input` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49602559/1364747

1. Try the 'input' event
2. Try the bind method and vnode if above doesn't work